# ASP.NET MVC - Version clarification

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using VS 2008 and MVC 1.0.

When i try to execute

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("DisplayHello",
new {Controller="SayHello",Action="DisplayHello"}) %>
```

it throws

```
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for "ActionLink".
```

I am using MVC Version `System.Web.Mvc.dll (1.0.40310.0)`

**Question**

What version do i need to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of MVC contains the ActionLink Extension. You likely have a namespace issue. Make sure your web.config includes the following:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
```

Also note your link is in incorrect format:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("DisplayHello", "DisplayHello", "SayHello") %>
```

Comment: Yes it was there.But the extension method was not found.

Comment: Oops ,I have to use Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink .

Comment: No.  That shouldn't be necessary.  As along as it knows about the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace, it should be able to resolve the extenion on the HtmlHelper without invoking the static method directly.